# Dynamic TABLE_DATE_RANGE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way of using a date variable as an argument of `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()`?

I mean, my goal is to analyze the behavior of users in the next week after they've purchased.

What I try to get is something like that:

```
TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.], 
                TIMESTAMP(purchaseDate), 
                TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(purchaseDate,7,'DAY')))
```

where I've previously calculated '`purchaseDate`', querying a fixed period of time. This will make dynamic the queried time range for each user. I'm not sure if this approach is against the BQ structure logic.

Comment: It should work fine. Could you add a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? When creating it you might very well find the problem yourself. Also, `DATE_ADD` always return a timestamp, so there's no need to use `TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Backlin. I'll work on this example ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

TABLE_DATE_RANGE will not accept any field names at least because none available at a time of evaluation

Comment: You have very light chance of addressing your challenge with TABLE_QUERY - but this depends on details. I recommend you to post separate question with details of your case

Comment: I've posted a new one in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243980/dynamic-date-range-with-table-query

Comment: One of the key things of SO is to describe _what_ you want, not _how_ to get it. Since both this question and the newer one you just posted ask for the same thing, but only differ in some technical details, they are essentially the same question. You should therefore update this question rather than reposting it as a new one. No hard feelings, but I'll flag a moderator for deleting the new one.

Comment: agree with @backlin. my suggestion was not about use TABLE_QUERY. not at all. My suggestion was to post question with real problem. The issue with current question is that it presents your wrong assumption about how your real ptoblem can be addressed. but this direction is wrong. so you need to present `what exactly you want to address`. again - the "new" question you posted is not a new but `exactly` the same as this one

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'm new here and I'm a bit lost with the procedure.

Comment: of course knowing site "procedure(s)" is important - you can start with [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Meantime - main idea is you ask we answer. You ask another question (in new post) we again answer - and so on. So this is Question/Answer site - not a forum where we discuss your project and complete it together. Nope! So, the issue you have now (from how I understand it) - you assumed that table wildcard function (TABLE_DATE_RANGE ) can help you in you task. You asked question very specific to this function useage. The answer you got should tell you that your guess

Comment: ... was wrong. So this post (question/answer) is "concluded". So, now you would want to ask another question - representing your original issue/task! and remember - the answer is as good as question is  - so - again - please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Hope this helps you to proceed right direction